# How to get current GPS location when my device restarted?.

Tags: android, gps, sms

My application send sms when the device get restarted.In the sms I try to send the current location of the device.I can get GPS location from the activity.but when i doing it background service it's not working.how to get current gps location when device restarted?.

Comment: I think there are many threads for getting location inside service. What is the specific problem that you are facing?

Comment: @Shobhit Puri When i call gps location inside the activity its working. locationManager = (LocationManager)Context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);But using the service what context i have to pass?..

Comment: you can use getLastKnownLOcationMethod() for getting the the current gps

Comment: call it from service you created

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your support.Finally I got the solution to get the current location and send sms with in service.

```
      locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 


            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                latitude ="";
            longitude = "";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "BOTH ARE NULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLocationChanged(location);

            }
            else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Network Enable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude =Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                            longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                        }
                    }
                }
               if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS Enable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude =Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                                longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
             SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
     smsMgr.sendTextMessage(send_no, null,"This is the new number location ="+ gpslocation, sentPI, null);
```

Write the code with in service onstart().Add all permissions on manifest file.Enable the GPS and enable mobile data before run the application.